# systemctl exits mono service with status=0/SUCCESS

Tags: service, mono, systemd, systemctl

I am attempting to launch a mono program with systemctl. My .service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts results sender
After=network.target systemd.mount

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /home/ubuntu/CameraInfoSender/CameraInfoSender.exe
```

,but it immediately exits with `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`, before doing any work. This command works when launched manually. Adding `Retart=on-success` doesn't help, nor does `WantedBy`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using the appropriate `Type=`. The `Type=` options are documented in `man systemd.service`.

Also check the answer the FAQ of [why things run in the shell but not via systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239).